# Node.js commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

While working on a discord bot I've been encountering an annoying error.

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js
null: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './command'
Require stack:

- c:...\commands\ping.js
- c:...\handlers\command-handler.js
- c:...\index.js
  Process exited with code 1

Through debugging I managed to narrow down the error to this segment of code but I have no idea why I am getting the errors I am getting or how to fix them.

```
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const { resolve } = require('path');

const commands = new Map();

const commandsDir = resolve('./commands');
const files = readdirSync(commandsDir);

for (const file of files) {
    const command = require(`${commandsDir}/${file}`);
    if (!command.name) continue;
    commands.set(command.name, command); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that `'./commands'` is a directory, by default node assumes its a js file.

change it to `'./commands/'`